# Webstorm node.js cli debugging in windows 7

Tags: webstorm

A noob needs a favour from you.  I am writing a node.js cli application that has to run in a windows 7 cmd.exe.  I can not figure out how to set up a debugging workflow that I am comfortable with.  When I use the standard node.js debugging config, it debugs in the Webstorm console (ie. in the ide, which does not seem to accept input from stdin - and yes, stdin has been resumed).  What I would like to achieve is to have it run the application in an external cmd.exe (which is what the app will be run in), and still be able set breakpoints etc in the ide.  I do not want to run the app in the Webstorm internal console.

I am using Webstorm 11 and node 4.2.1.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable stdin in WebStorm debugger console, in the Console tab uncheck "Use Console Input" — https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/43511007/s/Screen%20Shot%202015-04-30%20at%2014.45.54.png.

You can also run your application in cmd console with `--debug=<port for debugging>` or `--debug-brk=<port for debugging>` options and attach to it using `Remote Node.js Debug` configuration. See https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/Running+and+debugging+Node.js+application#RunninganddebuggingNode.jsapplication-DebuggingNode.jsappthatrunsremotely

Comment: Thank you.  The second solution was more what I was looking for.  I was trying to get my app launched in the console automatically by the IDE, and had kind of put  the horse before the cart when trying it out.